# Facebook API - Editing Fields from a posted feed message

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I created a script that publishes messages in a fan page feed. The script saves the post ID in a database for future use.

Sometimes, I need to edit the fields from this published posting. Example:

```
$feed_data = array(
    "message" => "message modified 2",
    "name" => "Test name",
    'caption' => 'Test Caption',
    "link" => "http://anylink.com.etc",
    'picture' => 'http://anypicture.com.etc',
    "access_token" => $page_access_token,
);

$facebook->api("/$post_id_from_database", "post", $feed_data);
```

But the only field modified in real post is the *message*. The others fields  were intact, with the values from original publishing.

Can anybody explain ? The Graph API only allow to edit message field ? The access token was generate using *publish_actions*, *manage_pages* and *publish_pages*.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post#updating says you can update all the fields listed in the publishing section of /page/feed. If that doesn’t work as documented, file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @CBroe Was just about to write the exact same :-)

Comment: thanks for orientation.. I opened a bug report.

Comment: The docs are incorrect ! We can only update the message field... The bug report link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1788556661371249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook official documentation is incorrect saying that you can update all fields in feed edge through Graph API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post#updating

You can only update the *message* field. See this bug report:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1788556661371249